# Plot3D with points on plot

Tags: plotting

I have function

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 3*x*y^2 + 12*x*y
```

and I used function

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

to plot them.  How do I add points from this array `{{0, -4}, {0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {2, -2}}`, that is, at locations `{{0,-4,f[0,-4]}, {0,0,f[0,0]}, ...}`?

Comment: How do you propose to add two-dimensional points on a 3D plot?

Comment: Do you want to display points like `{0, -4, f[0, -4]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 3 x y^2 + 12 x y;
myxypts = {{0, -4}, {0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {2, -2}};
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], 
  (Point@{#[[1]], #[[2]], f @@ #} & /@ myxypts)}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do what I guess you want to do, i.e. display points like `{0, -4, f[0, -4]}`, then I'd do

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 3*x*y^2 + 12*x*y
pt2 = {{0, -4}, {0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {2, -2}};
pts = {#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} & @@@ pt2
```

> {{0, -4, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {-2, -2, 16}, {2, -2, -16}}

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> Automatic], 
 ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Large]}]]
```

[image]